# cannot resolve requestPermissions in ActivityCompat

Tags: android

I need use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions();` but  with the message : `can not resolve .requestPermissions`. my `compileSdkVersion` is 26.

What can I do to solve this problem?

this is my code :

```
private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE = 10;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}
        , MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);
```

Comment: are you using any additional imported library in your project

Comment: Can you give a little detail of your code?

Comment: @ankuruniyal NO

Comment: I had the same problem, MOHS3N, and I'm very glad I found your question and the second answer, which fixed it for me and saved me *a lot* of time. It's a perfectly good question, as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put **`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`** outside any method you will get `can not resolve .requestPermissions` error.

Just put `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` inside onCreate or some other method. Like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()...
}
```

> You should follow good tutorials and read them carefully, coding is
>   not just copy and paste in your IDE.

Comment: You have made assumptions about how the OP's problem arised. They had a specific function call which was correct, but because of environment issues was producing a compiler error. The code itself is in numerous fragments which are supplied in response to errors introduced in working code by the upgrade to Android 7.0, when stricter management of permissions was required. The OP has posted the fragment which wasn't compiling, along with enough info to describe the problem. This answer does not fix the problem, unless it is a very basic newbie problem. The better answer is below, from @Mehrdad.

Answer (score 3):

i think you must use from below code

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

and use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is a very valuable answer. The OP's code fragment is in numerous places as the solution to other problems introduced with Android 7.0 (SDK23 and over), but the code fragments don't mention that one also needs to add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` to `build.gradle (Module: app)`. I wish I could upvote it more than once! @MOHS3N I suggest you reassign this as the correct answer.